# Why do setters need to return a value in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I was recently tripped up by the fact that the expected type of a setter that sets an `Int` is `Int -> Int`.

Why does a setter return a value? What significance does this value have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value that the setter returns is the value of the assignment expression.

For instance, if you were to do something like this:

```
public var x(setX, getX): Int

public function setX(val: Int): Int {
    return 5;
}

static function main() {
    neko.Lib.print(x = 2); // Prints 5
}
```

Haxe would print out 5. The setter returns the value of the set expression. Of course, it's a nonsensical value in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Small addition to other answers over here, it allows you to do this:

```
x = y = z = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the real world, it permits a way of implementing copy by value on assignment, eg:

```
public var pos(set_pos, default):Point;
function set_pos(newPos:Point) {
    pos.x = newPos.x
    pos.y = newPos.y;
    return pos;
}
```

And also of having a sensible return when implementing setters that can fail, eg:

```
public var positiveX(default, set_positiveX):Int;
function set_positiveX(newX:Int) {
    if (newX >= 0) x = newX;
    return x;
}

trace(x = 10); // 10
trace(x = -4); // 10
trace(x);      // 10
```

Whereas you would otherwise get something like this:

```
trace(x = 10); // 10
trace(x = -4); // -4
trace(x);      // 10
```

Which is what happens in AS3 even if the setter does not modify the value. If you could not do this, clearly the first, where x = -4 returns 10 is better :)